# multi colored plots in matplotlib plt based on certain properties of data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to color the line in a plot based on the following of a data set on the y axis.

```
if data > 0:
  color = 'r'
if data = 0:
  color = 'g'
if data < 0:
  color = 'b'
```

Unfortunately I only know how to color the entire data set one color. I also couldn't find anything on the web. I'm assuming there is a way to do this without breaking up the dataset for every time the color changes.

Below is an example of plotting the data with just one color.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Simple data 
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
data = np.sin(x ** 2)

#plot
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, data, color='r')

plt.show()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119165/changing-line-color
or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240694/python-how-to-plot-one-line-in-different-colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color parameter actually can take a list as an argument. For example, here's a simple bit of code that sets up a list of colors based on whether the data is positive or negative:

```
colors = []
for item in data:
    if item < 0:
        colors.append('r')
    else:
        colors.append('g')
```

then simply:

```
ax.bar(x, data, color=colors)
```

Edit: So I tested it, and it appears that my answer is only applicable for bar graphs. I couldn't find anything in the matplotlib documentation that seemed to indicate that coloring a line plot with multiple colors was possible. I did, however find [this site](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/dpsanders/matplotlib-examples/blob/master/colorline.ipynb), which I believe has the information you want. The guy there defines his own function to achieve it.

Using the file at my link, here is an equivalent version for a line graph:

```
cmap = ListedColormap(['r', 'g']) # use the colors red and green
norm = BoundaryNorm([-1000,0,1000], cmap.N) # map red to negative and green to positive
                                            # this may work with just 0 in the list
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
colorline(x, data, data, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

plt.xlim(x.min(), x.max())
plt.ylim(data.min(), data.max())

plt.show()
```

The last three arguments of colorline here tell it the color data and how to map it.

Comment: I get a huge error when i try this, i tried with both 2.7 and 3.3, i copied the code and error here http://pastebin.com/5DzfHRpb

Comment: @pyCthon Sorry about that. My original answer only works for bar graphs. I've updated it to include some information I found about doing the same with line graphs.

Comment: thanks! that was from the link some one commented in too

Comment: `scatter` will also take a list of colors.