# Error when trying to plot multi-colored line in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am unable to plot a variable where the points are coloured by reference to an index. What I ultimately want is the line-segment of each point (connecting to the next point) to be a particular colour. I tried with both `Matplotlib` and `pandas`. Each method throws a different error.

Generating a trend-line:

```
datums = np.linspace(0,10,5)
sinned = np.sin(datums)

plt.plot(sinned)
```

[image: edgy sin graph]

So now we generate a new column of the labels:

```
sinned['labels'] = np.where((sinned < 0), 1, 2)
print(sinned)
```

Which generate our final dataset:

```
          0  labels
0  0.000000       2
1  0.598472       2
2 -0.958924       1
3  0.938000       2
4 -0.544021       1
```

And now for the plotting attempt:

```
plt.plot(sinned[0], c = sinned['labels'])
```

Which results in the error: `length of rgba sequence should be either 3 or 4`

I also tried setting the labels to be the strings `'r'` or `'b'`, which didn't work either `:-/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: how to plot one line in different colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240694/python-how-to-plot-one-line-in-different-colors)

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240694/python-how-to-plot-one-line-in-different-colors Also,  there is a matplotlib [example about coloring lines](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Im just going through the questions you suggested now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 2 are not a color, `'b'`lue and `'r'`ed are used in the example below. You need to plot each separately.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

datums = np.linspace(0,10,5)

sinned = pd.DataFrame(data=np.sin(datums))
sinned['labels'] = np.where((sinned < 0), 'b', 'r')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for s in range(0, len(sinned[0]) - 1):
    x=(sinned.index[s], sinned.index[s + 1])
    y=(sinned[0][s], sinned[0][s + 1])
    ax.plot(x, y, c=sinned['labels'][s])
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]