# How to plot multi-color line if x-axis is date time index of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a multi-color line using pandas series. I know `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection` will sharply promote the efficiency.
But LineCollection require line segments must be float. I want to use datatime index of pandas as x-axis.

```
points = np.array((np.array[df_index.astype('float'), values]).T.reshape(-1,1,2))
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1],points[1:]], axis=1)
lc = LineCollection(segments)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.gca().add_collection(lc)
plt.show()
```

But the picture can't make me satisfied.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To produce a multi-colored line, you will need to convert the dates to numbers first, as matplotlib internally only works with numeric values.

For the conversion matplotlib provides `matplotlib.dates.date2num`. This understands datetime objects, so you would first need to convert your time series to datetime using `series.index.to_pydatetime()` and then apply `date2num`.

```
s = pd.Series(y, index=dates)
inxval = mdates.date2num(s.index.to_pydatetime())
```

You can then work with the numeric points as usual , e.g. plotting as Polygon or LineCollection[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240694/python-how-to-plot-one-line-in-different-colors),[2](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html)].

The complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

dates = pd.date_range("2017-01-01", "2017-06-20", freq="7D" )
y = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=len(dates)))

s = pd.Series(y, index=dates)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#convert dates to numbers first
inxval = mdates.date2num(s.index.to_pydatetime())
points = np.array([inxval, s.values]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1],points[1:]], axis=1)

lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap="plasma", linewidth=3)
# set color to date values
lc.set_array(inxval)
# note that you could also set the colors according to y values
# lc.set_array(s.values)
# add collection to axes
ax.add_collection(lc)


ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
monthFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%b")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthFmt)
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Since people seem to have problems abstacting this concept, here is a the same piece of code as above without the use of pandas and with an independent color array:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

dates = np.arange("2017-01-01", "2017-06-20", dtype="datetime64[D]" )
y = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=len(dates)))
c = np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=len(dates)))


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#convert dates to numbers first
inxval = mdates.date2num(dates)
points = np.array([inxval, y]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1],points[1:]], axis=1)

lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap="plasma", linewidth=3)
# set color to date values
lc.set_array(c)
ax.add_collection(lc)

ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `ax.plot(s.index, s.values, alpha=0.0) ` is it necessary? because I found it takes too much time.

Comment: No, it's not necessary. The reason I put it there is to let the plot autoscale. You can also set the limits manually using `xlim` and `ylim` instead.

Comment: I have met another problem using this method. Because I am plotting financial data, so the datetime index is not continuous, like 2017/6/21 11:30:00 is next to 2017/6/21 13:30:00. But on the plot, the time axis is continuous. So there are a lot of jumps on the plot. Is there any good solution for this?  Thank you for your kindness again!

Comment: Solution to what? What would be the desired outcome?

Comment: At present, there are redundant time coordinate, like 2017/6/21 11:31:00, which is not included in original data. I want to wipe out the redundant time coordinate. That is the desired outcome.

Comment: I have proposed it as a new question. You can go to this page to answer it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690454/how-to-remove-redundant-date-time-when-x-axis-is-incontinuous-pandas-datetimeind

Comment: You can use `ax.autoscale_view()` instead of the `ax.plot` line

Answer (score 1):

ImportanceOfBeingErnest's is a very good answer and saved me many hours of work. I want to share how I used above answer to change color based on signal from a pandas DataFrame.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import numpy as np
# import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm
```

Make test DataFrame

```
equity = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('20150701', periods=150))
equity['price'] = np.random.uniform(low=15500, high=18500, size=(150,))
equity['signal'] = 0
equity.signal[15:45] = 1
equity.signal[60:90] = -1
equity.signal[105:135] = 1

# Create a colormap for crimson, limegreen and gray and a norm to color
# signal = -1 crimson, signal = 1 limegreen, and signal = 0 lightgray
cmap = ListedColormap(['crimson', 'lightgray', 'limegreen'])
norm = BoundaryNorm([-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5], cmap.N)

# Convert dates to numbers
inxval = mdates.date2num(equity.index.to_pydatetime())

# Create a set of line segments so that we can color them individually
# This creates the points as a N x 1 x 2 array so that we can stack points
# together easily to get the segments. The segments array for line collection
# needs to be numlines x points per line x 2 (x and y)
points = np.array([inxval, equity.price.values]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1],points[1:]], axis=1)

# Create the line collection object, setting the colormapping parameters.
# Have to set the actual values used for colormapping separately.
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, linewidth=2)

# Set color using signal values
lc.set_array(equity.signal.values)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.autofmt_xdate()

# Add collection to axes
ax.add_collection(lc)

plt.xlim(equity.index.min(), equity.index.max())
plt.ylim(equity.price.min(), equity.price.max())
plt.tight_layout()

# plt.savefig('test_mline.png', dpi=150)
plt.show()
```