# pandas plot one line graph with color change on column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

My dataframe

`df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04', '2018-01-05'], 'b': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], 'c': [1,2,3,4,5]})`

```
         date  b  c
0  2018-01-01  a  1
1  2018-01-02  a  2
2  2018-01-03  b  3
3  2018-01-04  b  4
4  2018-01-05  c  5
```

I want to plot a line graph where X is `date`, y is `c` and the color of the line changes based on `b`. For this example there should be 3 different colors, the actual colors don't matter as long as their different.

I though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642966/how-to-plot-multi-color-line-if-x-axis-is-date-time-index-of-pandas) would work but it doesn't allow the change of color by column.

The output should be *one* line that changes color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try:

```
_, ax = plt.subplots()
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
colors = {'a':'r', 'b':'b','c':'c'}
for n, g in df.groupby('b'):
     g.plot('date','c', marker='o', ax=ax, color=colors[n])

ax.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You basically want to create a new series for each value in column `b`.  One way to do that is to group on `date` and `b` and then unstack `b`, and the other method is to use `pivot`.  Then just plot the result.

```
df.pivot(index='date', columns='b').droplevel(0, axis=1).plot(colors='rbc')  
# 'rbc' = ['red', 'blue', 'cyan'] 
# These colors are based on the column ordering, e.g. 'a', 'b', 'c'.
```

To be more explicit with the colors:

```
colors = {
    'a': 'red',
    'b': 'blue',
    'c': 'cyan'
}
(df
 .pivot(index='date', columns='b')
 .droplevel(0, axis=1)[colors.keys()]
 .plot(colors=colors.values())
)
```

[image]

Comment: hmm....would there be a way to add a color mapping for the values of  column `b`, like `{'a': 'red', 'b': 'blue', 'c': 'cyan'}`

Comment: I don't think you can with a line chart.  With a scatter plot, you can try something like `df.assign(days=df['date'].diff().dt.days.fillna(0).cumsum()).plot(kind='scatter', x='days', y='c', colors=df['b'].map({'a': 'red', 'b': 'blue', 'c': 'cyan'}))`. I am assuming here that the `date` column is timestamps rather than text.