# How to base color line segment on value of a string/ other column?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

dataframe with 3 columns

```
x       y     type
21/02   5     'a'
22/02   6     'b'
...   ...   ...
```

in total i have two type: `'a' and 'b'`

based on a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240694/python-how-to-plot-one-line-in-different-colors) and [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html) i came with following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()   
xy = np.column_stack((df['x'],df['y'])) 
xy = xy.reshape(-1, 1, 2) 
segments = np.hstack([xy[:-1], xy[1:]]) 
coll = LineCollection(segments, color='r') 
ax.add_collection(coll)
plt.show()
```

This gives me following graph:

[image]

I think I have to do something with: `coll.set_array(some_value)`
But I don't know how.

I got this far: 
I used same code as above but just changed one line:

```
coll = LineCollection(segments,cmap=plt.cm.gist_ncar)
```

[image]

But now the color of the segments are at random.

How do I base the color of the segments on the column 'type' in my dataframe?

Comment: What is `ax` in `ax.add_collection(coll)`?

Comment: good eye. I edited the code. It is ax object.

Comment: where is the code for the second plot

Comment: thanks for comment. Edited the question.

Comment: answer for this question is a simple if statement.. you can do it anyway you like. just compare the df["type']

Comment: if you want the colors to be random try using a loop to plot one by one instead of plotting everything together

Answer (score 2):

If you just have two colors, this should work:

```
colors = ["red" if type=="a" else "blue" for type in df["type"]] 
coll = LineCollection(segments, color=colors)
```

For more colors you can map the types to a list of colors in a similar way.

Comment: do you mean: `coll = LineCollection(segments, color=colors)`  ?

Comment: color = 'r' will always keep it red

Comment: Yes, my bad :D Edited it.

Comment: Bam! Works like a charm. Didn’t know you could pass a list with colors with same length as number of lines in collection. Tnx