# Matplotlib to plot a continuous plot having different colours in different sections

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

[image]So I want to find the way to change the plot every single time whenever it reaches a new month. So for example, when it reaches January the plot will be blue, when it reaches February the plot will be red etc till December.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # Monthly average precipitation
    boulder_monthly_precip = [0.70, 0.75, 1.85, 2.93, 3.05, 2.02, 
                              1.93, 1.62, 1.84, 1.31, 1.39, 0.84]
     
    months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", 
              "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    
    for i in range(len(months)):
   ...:     if months[i] == "Jan":
   ...:         colour = "red"
   ...:         plt.plot(boulder_monthly_precip, months, color=colour)
   ...:     elif months[i] == "Feb":
   ...:         colour = "green"
   ...:         plt.plot(boulder_monthly_precip, months, color=colour)
   ...:     elif months[i] == 'Mar':
   ...:         colour = "orange"
   ...:         plt.plot(boulder_monthly_precip, months, color=colour)
   ...:     elif months[i] == "July":
   ...:         colour = "yellow"
   ...:         plt.plot(boulder_monthly_precip, months, color=colour)
```

And the result is:[image]

Comment: [Like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17241345/8881141)

Comment: @Mr.T something like this but with my data. I have seen this example but I couldnt figure out how to do it

Comment: What was the specific problem that prevented you from implementing it with your data?

Comment: Instead of making a multicoloured plot, it only changes to one colour to (December colour)

Comment: @JanKlimaszewski Check out [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html).

Comment: @JanKlimaszewski I suggest you update the question with your new approach and the incorrect outcome. Please be reminded that a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) improves your chance to receive good answers.

Comment: @Mr.T I have updated the question.

Comment: @a_guest I tried but it didnt work for me

Comment: @JanKlimaszewski You need to clip the range like `plt.plot(boulder_monthly_precip[i:i+1], months[i:i+1], color=colour)`

Comment: @a_guest It is not working

Comment: @JanKlimaszewski What exactly is not working?

Comment: @a_guest The graph is empty

Comment: @JanKlimaszewski Indeed, you need to step by 2, i.e. `plt.plot(boulder_monthly_precip[i:i+2], months[i:i+2], color=colour)`. And then only run for `range(len(months)-1)`.

Comment: @a_guest Can you explain why there is +2 in the index?

Comment: @JanKlimaszewski Slices like `x:y` exclude the second element `y`, e.g. `0:4` includes the indices `[0, 1, 2, 3]` but excludes `4`. So for each line segment you want two consecutive data points, starting at index `i` and this you can achieve by `i:i+2`. It means include points `[i, i+1]` but exclude `i+2`.